# C++ ofstream vs. C++ cout piped to file

Tags: c++, cout, ofstream

I'm writing a set of unit tests that write calculated values out to files. Each test produces a square matrix that holds anywhere from 50,000 to 500,000 doubles, and I have a total of 128 combinations of test cases.

Is there any significant overhead involved in writing cout statements and then piping that output to files, or would I be better off writing directly to the file using an ofstream?

Answer (score 8):

This is going to be dependent on your system and environment. This likely to be very little difference, but there is only one way to be sure: try both approaches and measure them.

Answer (score 1):

Since the dimensions involved are so large I'm assuming that these files are not meant to be read by a human being? Just make sure you write them out as binary and not human-readable text because that will make so much more difference than the difference between using ofstream or piping cout.

Whether this means you *have* to use ofstream or not I don't know. I've never written binary to cout so I can't say whether that's possible...

Comment: Hmmm, another answer, another anonymous downvote. If I didn't know better I'd say someone with a grudge was following me around...

Answer (score 0):

As Charles Bailey said, it's implementation dependent; what follows is mostly for linux implementation with gnu toolchain, but I hardly imagine it being very different in other os.

In libstdc++ 4.4.2:

- An fstream contain an underlying stdio_filebuf which is a basic_filebuf. This basic_filebuf contain it's own buffer by inheriting basic_streambuf, and actually contain a __basic_file, itself containing an underlying plain C stdio abstraction (FILE* or std::__c_file*), in which it flush the buffer.
- cout, which is an ostream is initialized with a stdio_sync_filebuf itself initialized with the C file abstraction stdout. stdio_sync_filebuf call plain C stdio functions.

Considering only C++, it appear that an fstream *may* be more efficient thanks to two layers of buffer.

Considering C only, if the process is forked with the stdout file descriptor redirected in a file, there should be no difference between writing to a new opened file (what fstream does at the end) or to stdout since the fd point to a file anyway (what cout does at the end).

If I were you, I would use an fstream since it's your intent.