# c++ cout redirected to file works slower than using ofstream

Tags: c++, cout, ostream

I have an application that have to iterate over every character (to check some special cases) and write it to a stream using ostream put method.

When writing the ostream* points to a file stream, it executes magnificently faster than when ostream* points to cout which is redirected to a file.

In this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1697906/12074577) answer I saw that probable using the fstream will be faster, due to one more layer of buffering compared to cout.
I thought that when I know that the output is going to cout, I can go through a string buffer, and when the buffer is full, append it to cout.
This way I obtain another layer of buffering and performance will improve.

So I have a test here of writing 32 million rows, each row is a string of ten characters.
I write them using cout, fstream, and stringbuffer that is later appended to cout.

```
void print_to_ostream(ostream *out, string& ones)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32000000; ++i){

            const char* ones_char = ones.c_str();
            for (int j = 0; j < ones.size(); ++j ){
                out->put(ones_char[j]);
            }
        }
}

int main(void){
    string ones ="1111111111";


    ostream *out = &cout;
    size_t cout_time = 0;
    size_t file_time = 0;
    size_t cout_buffered_time = 0;

    // print cout using ostream
    mono_tick_timer time;
    print_to_ostream(out, ones);
    cout_time += time.tick();

    // write to file using ostream
    ofstream file("/tmp/test_file");
    out = &file;
    time.tick();
    print_to_ostream(out, ones);
    file_time += time.tick();

    // ***optional solution***
    // print to cout but passing through a string buffer
    stringstream buffer;
    out = &buffer;

    time.tick();
    print_to_ostream(out, ones);
    cout_buffered_time += time.tick();
    cout << buffer.str();
    size_t buf_to_cout = time.tick();


    std::cerr << "cout time: " <<  (double)cout_time / 1e6 << endl;
    std::cerr << "file time: " <<  (double)file_time / 1e6 << endl;
    std::cerr << "cout buffered time: " <<  (double)cout_buffered_time / 1e6 << endl;
    std::cerr << "buf_to_cout: " <<  (double)buf_to_cout / 1e6 << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

The results of running `./a.out > /tmp/test_times`
are as follow (milliseconds):

```
cout time: 4773.62
file time: 2391.52
cout buffered time: 2380.83
buf_to_cout: 131.615
```

My bottom line question is: is using stringstream as a buffer before appending everything to cout a good solution? 
Considering the fact that sometimes cout is redirected with large output to a file, and sometimes it's just being printed to the console?

Are they any negative side effects I didn't think about with this solution?
Or there is a better one I didn't think about?

Comment: Maybe add a `buffer <<std::flush()` and include that in the timing for the final case.  Your data may be sitting in memory still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The global streams (e.g. `std::cout`) are [`sync_with_stdio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) by default, whereas `std::ofstream` is not:

> By default, all eight standard C++ streams are synchronized with their respective C streams.
>
> If the synchronization is turned off, the C++ standard streams are allowed to buffer their I/O independently, which may be considerably faster in some cases.

Try turning it off with `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);`.

Comment: Thanks, 
The time difference dropped by an order of magnitude and is now:

    cout time: 2572.32
    file time: 2500.15
    cout buffered time: 2447.